# A variant of polar ratio of uniforms method for Cauchy variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, algorithms, cauchy-distribution

The [Handbook of Monte Carlo Methods](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470177934.html) (page 107., Algorithm 4.27) presents a variant of the polar ratio of uniforms method for generating standard Cauchy distributed variables:

[image: Algorithm 4.27, page 107., Handbook of Monte Carlo Methods, Dirk P. Kroese, Thomas Taimre, Zdravko I. Botev]

The better known version of the algorithm, also presented in [Numerical Methods of Statistics](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521191586) (page 316., Algorithm C4) differs from the above algorithm by:

2A. Set $V = 2V-1$.

So in the first algorithm $V \in (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$, while in the second $V \in (-1, 1)$.

Are these two algorithms yet statistically equivalent?

---

**UPDATE**

The above error is now listed in the errata of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second algorithm implements the ratio of uniforms method correctly (as I understand it), and appears to produce a standard Cauchy result.

The first doesn't look quite right algebraically, with a result that the region in which the uniforms are generated doesn't include all of the required curved region,

[image: plots of the acceptance regions for the two methods]

nor does the result seem to be standard Cauchy. Here's standard-Cauchy P-P plots of large samples from each:

[image: P-P plots of large samples from both methods]

You can see the second produces a straight-line but the first doesn't; only the second appears consistent with having been drawn from a standard Cauchy.

I note further that the second is consistent with the algorithm Luc Devroye gives for the polar method for the Cauchy (differing only in that the denominator uniform includes a sign, which doesn't change the distribution of the result).

Comment: Then I report it to the author to be part of the errata. I suspected it cannot be correct.